# GeoIP (GeoLite2-Country.mmdb) IPv6 less database records: 800k+ (8th of July 2015 12:42:20) to 320k+ (3rd of September 2015 03:07:26)

Tags: geoip, maxmind, geolite2

I'm using GeoIP free database (GeoLite2-Country.mmdb) for a PrestaShop plugin in order to detect visitor country.

I noticed that from one version:

DB Size:    4.66M (4,888,549 bytes), **802,421 records**

DB Version:     2.0 (**07/08/2015 12:42:20**) - IPv6

to new one:

DB Size     1.9M (1,996,925 bytes), **320,883 records**

DB Version  2.0 (**09/03/2015 03:07:26**) - IPv6

number of records dropped from 802,421 to 320,883, althought 320k+ one is a newer version.

Does anybody have any idea why did number of records drop from one version to a newer version? Is the new version at same level of accuracy (or better) than the old one?

Thank you,
Andy

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a detailed information about the changes. However, each row of record is a range of IP address. So it is possible that a further compression of range could reduce the number of rows without changing the accuracy.

For example:

> "1","2","LOCATION A" "3","5","LOCATION A"

Compressed:

> "1","5","LOCATION A"

Comment: I was thinking about this, but wanted to be sure this is the case as difference in number of records is about 500k...